# in D3 version 4, I'm trying to make 2 charts responsive on the same HTML page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive-design

Using D3, I have two charts on one page with no issue. But I'm trying to resize both using this function, which works about 80%.(100% with one chart on the page)
Chart 2 is perfect on resize but chart 1 takes the x and y axis of chart 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

this fiddle contains the code used. the csv data is in the HTML part in pre tags. its not showing the result because the csv data is normally in a file, not sure how to link the two.

https://jsfiddle.net/36qqd5kf/1/

```
function resize() {
/* Find the new window dimensions */
var width = parseInt(d3.select("#chart1").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = parseInt(d3.select("#chart1").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

/* Update the range of the scale with new width/height */
x.range([0, width]),
y.range([height, 0]);

// Update the axis with the new scale
g.select('.axis.axis--x')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %Y")));

g.select('.axis.axis--y')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Force D3 to recalculate and update the line
g.selectAll(".line")
   .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); }) ;

//Update the axis with the new scale Chart2 update
var width = parseInt(d3.select("#chart2").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = parseInt(d3.select("#chart2").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

x.range([0, width]),
y.range([height, 0]);

g2.select('.axis.axis--x')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %Y")));

g2.select('.axis.axis--y')
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

/* Force D3 to recalculate and update the line */
g2.selectAll(".line")
   .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); }) ;
}


d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Comment: You're setting the axes twice as the `select` function doesn't distinguish between the `g` and `g2`.  You'll want to restrict the selections to the chart ids - or something along those lines.

Comment: You need to provide some more code.  What are `g`, `g2`, `x` and `y`?  This question, in it's current form, can not be answered.

Comment: g is from chart 1. g2 is from chart 2 and x and y are present in both